# Python Request binary content

Tags: python, json, binary, python-requests

I'm trying to get JSON from a Google Trends URL, but I can't convert it to JSON because content goes as b''. How I can get this result as JSON?

My simple code:

```
import requests
r = requests.get('https://trends.google.ru/trends/api/stories/latest?hl=ru&tz=-180&cat=all&fi=15&fs=15&geo=RU&ri=300&rs=15&sort=0')
print(r.content)
```

`r.content` starts with:

> b')]}\'\n{"featuredStoryIds":[],"trendingStoryIds":["RU_lnk_iJ8H1AAwAACP-M_ru","RU_lnk_7H7L0wAwAAAnHM_ru","RU_lnk_Q-IB1AAwAABChM_ru","RU_lnk_EErj0wAwAADzKM_ru","RU_lnk_VY2s0wAwAAD57M_ru","RU_lnk_sdUP1AAwAAC-sM_ru","RU_lnk_ILv60wAwAADa2M_ru","RU_lnk_O6j70wAwAADAyM_ru","RU_lnk_fVQS1AAwAABvMM_ru","RU_lnk_TJ8D1AAwAABP-M_ru","RU_lnk_I97F0wAwAADmvM_ru","RU_lnk_tCrq0wAwAABeSM_ru","RU_lnk_W8EA1AAwAABbpM_ru","RU_lnk_IYX90wAwAADc5M_ru","RU_lnk_bz4M1AAwAABjWM_ru","RU_lnk_EJ-...

Decoding this with the `r.json()` method fails:

```
simplejson.scanner.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)
```

Comment: `r.content` is indeed the raw binary data. Have you looked at the [`response.json()` method](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/quickstart/#json-response-content) yet? What happens when you call that?

Comment: yep, simplejson.scanner.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are contacting a Google service, and Google is prefixing JSON with some extra data to [prevent JSON hijacking](http://haacked.com/archive/2009/06/25/json-hijacking.aspx/):

```
>>> import requests
>>> r = requests.get('https://trends.google.ru/trends/api/stories/latest?hl=ru&tz=-180&cat=all&fi=15&fs=15&geo=RU&ri=300&rs=15&sort=0')
>>> r.content[:10]
b')]}\'\n{"fea'
```

Note the `)]}'` and newline characters at the start.

You need to remove this extra data first and manually decode; there are no other newlines in the payload so we can just split on the newline:

```
import json

json_body = r.text.splitlines()[-1]
json_data = json.loads(json_body)
```

I used `Response.text` here to get decoded string data (the server sets the correct content type encoding in the headers).

This gives you a decoded dictionary:

```
>>> json_body = r.text.splitlines()[-1]
>>> json_data = json.loads(json_body)
>>> type(json_data)
<class 'dict'>
>>> sorted(json_data)
['date', 'featuredStoryIds', 'hideAllImages', 'storySummaries', 'trendingStoryIds']
```

Comment: TypeError: the JSON object must be str, not 'bytes'

Comment: @KonstantinRusanov: ah, older Python 3 version, 3.6 accepts bytes. Will update.

Comment: Perfect! Thanks a lot

Answer (score -2):

Maybe try this it it might help:

```
 import requests
    r = requests.get('https://trends.google.ru/trends/api/stories/latest?hl=ru&tz=-180&cat=all&fi=15&fs=15&geo=RU&ri=300&rs=15&sort=0')
    page=r.status_code
    print page
```